# Argument for SubscriberStatusCallback in advertise

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The C++ ros::NodeHandle API provides an advertise method with connection and disconnection callbacks that are executed after subscription and unsubscription respectively.

According to the API, ([here](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1NodeHandle.html#a2d81fe5562417931bd7634490c364473)), the callback signature is:

```
 void connectCallback(const ros::SingleSubscriberPublisher& pub)
     {
     // Do something
     }
 handle.advertise<std_msgs::Empty>("my_topic", 1, connectCallback);
```

So the question is, what is the argument of the callback intended for?
Is it the publisher that the advertise() method returns?
Probably should be documented in the API doc (//Do something does not get any clue about that).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11327/argument-for-subscriberstatuscallback-in-advertise/) by [joanpau](https://answers.ros.org/users/893/joanpau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 191 on 2011-09-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As described in the [API docs](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1SingleSubscriberPublisher.html), you can use that argument to publish a message to *only* the newly connected subscriber. A normal `ros::Publisher` publishes to every subscriber. It can also tell you the name of the newly subscribed node, which may be useful for debugging.

You almost never actually need that single-subscriber-publishing ability though. The obvious use case is sending the most recently published message to the new subscriber, but you can get that behavior just by advertising with `latch=true`.

In my code, I often want to know when nodes (un)subscribe to a topic, but I don't need the `SingleSubscriberPublisher`. I use this idiom:

```
class CameraDriver
{
  image_transport::ImageTransport it_;
  image_transport::CameraPublisher pub_;

  // NOTE: No SingleSubscriberPublisher argument
  void connectCb()
  {
    if (pub_.getNumSubscribers() == 0)
      stopCamera(); // Don't waste CPU if noone listening!
    else
      startCamera();
  }

  // In constructor or nodelet::onInit()
  CameraDriver()
  {
    // Monitor whether anyone is subscribed to the camera stream
    image_transport::SubscriberStatusCallback image_cb =
      boost::bind(&CameraDriver::connectCb, this);
    ros::SubscriberStatusCallback info_cb =
      boost::bind(&CameraDriver::connectCb, this);
    pub_ = it_.advertiseCamera("image_raw", 1, image_cb, image_cb,
                               info_cb, info_cb);
  }
};
```

There's a fair amount of C++ magic going on here. Let's break down this line:

```
ros::SubscriberStatusCallback info_cb = boost::bind(&CameraDriver::connectCb, this);
```

On the right side, we create a Boost.Bind object, binding our class instance `this` to its member function `connectCb`. The Boost.Bind object behaves like a functor; we could call it with no arguments (since `connectCb` has no arguments), and that would be the same as writing `this->connectCb()`. A sneaky feature of Boost.Bind is that we could also call it with any number of extra arguments; the Bind object would silently discard the extra arguments and again call `this->connectCb()`.

Now we assign the Bind object to a `ros::SubscriberStatusCallback`, which is a typedef for `boost::function<void(const ros::SingleSubscriberPublisher&)>`. In other words, a functor taking a single argument of type `ros::SingleSubscriberPublisher`. `info_cb` is a Boost.Function object wrapping a Boost.Bind object wrapping `this->connectCb()`.

Time passes, and a node subscribes to the camera info topic. Somewhere in the bowels of roscpp, our `NodeHandle` calls `info_cb(pub)`, passing in a `ros::SingleSubscriberPublisher`. `info_cb` in turn calls the wrapped Bind object, which discards the argument and finally calls `this->connectCb()`. Voila!

I've complicated the example by using [image_transport](http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_transport), but there's a reason for that. `image_transport` has its own `image_transport::SingleSubscriberPublisher` type mirroring the ROS version. By using the Bind trick, I can use `connectCb` for both image topics (possibly compressed by `image_transport`) and other message topics.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2011-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7